# C3P0 acquiring Maxpool randomly

Tags: java, c3p0

C3PO connection is acquiring the Max pool size connection with test connection using preferred Test query which stays idle and after sometime it gets cleared by itself.

1. Need to know when does C3PO triggers ConnectionTester.(This is must is it Timer or event driven)
2. How to make sure the this Test-connection does stay idle and gets clear sooner.(This i believe existing setup clears the idle connection)
3. How to make sure only some amount of connection is tested and not max.Can i use acquire increment?

Jar used:

```
c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar
```

Below is config:

```
initialSize=15

maxActive=300

minPoolSize=15

maxIdleTime=3600

maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=600

maxConnectionAge=36000

testConnectionOnCheckin=true

preferredTestQuery=select 1 from dual

idleConnectionTestPeriod=30000
```

Comment: connection testing has nothing to do with growing the pool. it looks like you are testing connections every 30 seconds while they are idle and and on connection checkin. but it's hard to tell as this is not a valid c3p0 config. if it were a properties file, you'd need to prepend "c3p0." to most of the values. c3p0 has no config parameters "initialSize" or "maxActive". see [a list of c3p0 config parameters](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties)

Comment: Hi Steven,Thanks for the reply.Actually, c3p0 prepend is there in actual properties file.The behaviour of system is such that within 5 mins the connection gets increase from ~20 to 300 and all the new connection is having select 1 from dual sql running.So,I need to figure what is triggering Testconnection.

Comment: the connection test will be triggered by Connection check-ins and every 30 seconds while Connections are idle. they will also occur when a Connection experiences and Exception. the Connection tests are not triggering an expansion of the pool. Only calls to `getConnection()` can do that.

Comment: @SteveWaldman I read your article on link.I have below questions.https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues/65.  
1.When does the C3PO pool size increases and when does it shrinks?
2.Will have numconnections=numidleconnections=maxpoolSize will cause any issues?As per my knowledge High numBusyConnections can cause issue to Application.